# Does calling [view setNeedsDisplay] for a view behind another semi-transparent view not invoke drawRect:?

Tags: iphone, ios, alpha, drawrect, subviews

I have two views:

View A with alpha 1.0
View B with alpha 0.5

Both are subviews, with view B added as a subview after view A which implies that the opaque view A is partially visible through the semi-transparent view B.

When I call `setNeedsDisplay` on both views, only view B's `drawRect` is invoked.

I am aware that `setNeedsDisplay` doesn't immediately invoke `drawRect` so I guess if A was completely invisible, this would make sense.

When I can see part of view A through B, why is A's `drawRect` still not get invoked? 
Maybe I didn't understand the documentation correctly?

Comment: what if you remove View B (so it's not obscuring View A) does your view redraw itself as you think it should?

Comment: This is just a theory, but make sure View B's `opaque` property is set to NO. This is a seperate property from `alpha` and is used by the OS to perform drawing optimisations - like, perhaps, preventing the drawing of views underneath.

Comment: @Jessedc Yes it does. When I have a single view present, it renders exactly as it should....

Comment: @Xono Unfortunately, that did not work :( Really good suggestion though....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question - drawRect is not invoked in this case.